# Trying to get a button and edittext to not appear for a android app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-edittext, android-button

I have a Android App that uses Google Maps, if the GPS acquire a connection to the Android Device I have a Button and EditText that I do not want to show up.  The code for the On Create method is below.

If the isGPS is true the button and label still show up.  I acutally want to have the button and the edittext not appear when isGPS is true.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    final boolean isGPS = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map_view_wogps);

    showCurrentLocationOnMap(); 

    // Getting reference to btn_find of the layout activity_main
    Button btn_find = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_find);
    final EditText etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_location);
    if (isGPS){
        btn_find.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        etLocation.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    // Defining button click event listener for the find button
    OnClickListener findClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // Getting user input location
            String location = etLocation.getText().toString();

            if(location!=null && !location.equals("")){
                AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Address>> execute = new GeocoderTask().execute(location);
            }
        }
    };

    // Setting button click event listener for the find button
    btn_find.setOnClickListener(findClickListener);




    try {
        showSheltersAndFuelStops();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to set their visibility to View.VISABLE when ever the GPS is turned off.

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in my question I actually do need to get the edittext and button to disappear if the isGPS is false.

Comment: what is the current state? what happens when you run this code?

Comment: I acutally want to have the button and the edittext not appear when isGPS is true, but the edittext and button always appear.

Answer (score 0):

You need to negate isGPS:

```
if(!isGPS) {
  // This gets run ig isGPS is false
}
```

Comment: If the isGPS is true I need to have the Button and the EditText to not show up.'

Comment: Sorry I had a type on my question.

Comment: Most likely, you will solve this by running the debugger and looking at the value of isGPS. My guess is that your assumption is wrong and the gps is never enabled, so the buttons are never hidden.

Answer (score -1):

Your if statement is checking if isGPS is true, and then setting the buttons to be invisible if it is.

By the sounds of it you want to set the buttons to invisible only if isGPS is false.

You need `if (!isGPS)` instead of `(isGPS)`

Comment: If the isGPS is true I need to have the Button and the EditText to not show up.'

Comment: Sorry I had a type on my question.

Comment: I acutally want to have the button and the edittext not appear when isGPS is true.

Comment: Would recommend stepping through it line by line to make sure those setVisibility statements are actually getting hit - isGPS might not be behaving the way you expect